# Need help on a method in C

Tags: c, function

I want to ask if someone can help me with one function.I want to give an input to my function (for example 4) and the function will produces the following  numbers :

1-222-33333-44444444

I don't want just to print them i want to produce them so i can save these numbers into a table.

```
for(r=1; r<=num; r++)
{
   for(sp=num-r; sp>0; sp--)
      printf(" ");
   for(c=1; c<=r; c++)
      printf("%d", r);
   for(k=2; k<=r; k++)
      printf("%d", r);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: i can only print these numbers with some nested for loops but it doesnt help me:(

Comment: for(r=1; r<=num; r++)
{         
  for(sp=num-r; sp>0; sp--)
      printf(" ");
      for(c=1; c<=r; c++)
          printf("%d", r);                                          
          for(k=2; k<=r; k++)
              printf("%d", r);
              printf("\n");
          }

Comment: As a new user (and you skipped taking the [introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) you may not realize what the Edit button is for. Look: your code in the comment is practically unreadable. (Hey, a friendly person already did it for you.)

Comment: I forgot to say that the num is the input value for my function,the other variables are just integers.

Comment: Yep forgive me im new here :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from question what you are trying to accomplish. Assuming that you want to generate C-string as `"1-222-33333-44444444"` here is one solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *produce_char_sequence(int n);

int main(void)
{
    char* str = produce_char_sequence(4);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}

char *produce_char_sequence(int n)
{
    int i, j, idx;

    char *str = malloc(n * (n + 1)); // n**2 + n - 1 + 1
    if (str == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory by malloc\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    idx = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 2*i - 1; j++)
            str[idx++] = '0' + i;
        if (i != n) // unless within last iteration
            str[idx++] = '-';
    }
    str[idx] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

The number of characters is coming from `1 + 3 + 5 + .. + 2n-1` [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), that sums up to n<sup>2</sup>. Then you need also space for n-1 `'-'` characters and one for ending *null character*.

Note that `n` is likely to be limited up to `9`. See example at http://ideone.com/Gi7KxG.

Comment: Thanks man!So you save these numbers 1-222-...into str right ?

Comment: @AneokoenaAneokoena: In fact I didn't, `produce_char_sequence()` function does if you read it carefully. Variable `idx` keeps track of current position within `str` buffer (that one, that is allocated by `malloc()` call, note that `sizeof(char)` is always one). It's incremented after every assignment (well, in except to last one). Of course it's starting from zero. You can use array or pointer style accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (j = 2*i; j > 1; j--)
            printf("%d", i);
        printf("-");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ye i know its working :D.But i want to save these values into a table.Is this thing possible ?